# TeamCity, how to get names of the files edited

Tags: version-control, teamcity

I am using TeamCity and I am new to it. I have added a Build Configuration to the TeamCity and I created one VCS root to attach to it.

However, my project have a special requirement to detect a particular file that was changed in the VCS root location and use that file in build step. I am sure this could be done in TeamCity, I am not able to figure out how.

Any help? Thanks,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To get the names of the files changed this is what I did. Thanks to Sam Jones.

I used `System.TeamCity.build.changedFiles.file` variable as follows.

1. Add a command line build step
2. Select Run as Custom Script
3. Add the script `copy "%system.teamcity.build.changedFiles.file%" changelog.txt` in script box.

You will get the changes in changelog.txt file in the format specified on [this link](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Risk+Tests+Reordering+in+Custom+Test+Runner).

**NOTE:** `teamcity.build.changedFiles.file` does not work. You need to use `system.teamcity.build.changedFiles.file`

Comment: Alternatively you can add additional parameter with "-DchangedFiles=%system.teamcity.build.changedFiles.file%" in the build step & retrieve as system property inside your application

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you want a VCS Trigger that specifies VCS Trigger Rules, so that a build configuration will run when someone makes a change to a particular file. The [documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-VCSTriggerRules) has some nice examples of how to do this. If you're trying to trigger a build on one particular file, try this:

```
+:foo/bar.txt
```

This excludes all files from the trigger rule and then includes bar.txt in the foo directory. Paths are relative to the root of the repository (do not include a preceding slash). If someone modifies foo/bar.txt, the build configuration will be triggered to run.

VCS Trigger Rules also support pattern matching and all sorts of other options. Check out the documentation.

Comment: If I have more than one files say bar.txt, bar1.txt, bar2.txt? Can I add trigger for each one of them?

Comment: Could this be done without knowing the file names in the directory? If I do it like `+:foo/*.txt` would I be able to get the particular file name that was edited?

Comment: Yes, you can add as many files as you like. You can do `+:bar.txt`, `+:bar1.txt`, `+:bar2.txt`, etc. Or you can specify all files in a directory with `+:foo/**`.

Comment: There are a couple of predefined build parameters that might be of use. One is `teamcity.build.triggeredBy` that describes how the build was triggered. The other is `teamcity.build.changedFiles.file` that is a path to a file with info about changed files in the build. You can read more about these parameters [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters).